# Simplifying complex equation using polar coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$z_2=\dfrac{\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}+2i}{5i+(1+i)^2} + \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}{\sqrt{3}-2i}$$

I should simplify this using polar coordinates, but I just do not know how to start. I simplified the denominator using the conjugate of both the first and the second term, but I cannot find the same base for both to use polar coordinates.

Comment: Hopefully you can see it now.

Comment: I think you should write out what you've done. What does the simplified form that you do have look like?

Comment: Does the question say simplify using polar coordinates or write in polar coordinates? If the latter, then just reduce in the normal way to the form $a+ib$ (you should get denominator 7 for both terms) then convert that to polar form.

Comment: I got z2 = 3/7-3/(7*sqrt(3)*i).

Comment: Which is $\frac{3+\sqrt{3}i}{7}$

Comment: @Paul 
 
So should it be = sqrt((12/49)))^i*pi/6?

Comment: In $(r,\theta)$ form it is $( \frac{\sqrt{12}}{7}, \frac{\pi}{6})$

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. :)